# How do I convert all occurrences of the word “OLD” in some file with the word “NEW” in Linux

Tags: linux

Can someone give me a command that convert all occurrences of the word “OLD” in some file with the word “NEW” in Linux?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/OLD/NEW/g' <file >newfile
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot tom. It took me a while to figure this out. Godbless